# What function is linear in origin and has an asymptote of y=0?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

It would look something like this.

[image]

Comment: $\frac x{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example that comes to mind would be $y=xe^{-x^2}$[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this (type of) function has a name?

Comment: @Zack I don't know, sorry.